# What does the chainring have to do with SRAM YAW

Tags: derailleur, chainring

I'm shopping for 110 BCD chain rings and I noticed that some of the SRAM ones are labeled "YAW FD only".  As far as I can tell the derailleur doesn't touch the chainring so whats so special?  Can I safely use this chainring with a shimano FD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [SRAM](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/technologies/yaw) on YAW:
"The front derailleur cage rotates to maintain a consistent angular relationship with the chain. Yaw technology eliminates the need for shifter trim. As a result, shifts feel more direct, more precise, and combined with the new Red crankset and chainrings, delivers an unmatched performance advantage in front shifting."

According to [Velonews](http://velonews.competitor.com/2012/03/news/it-works-we-test-sram-red-backwards-compatibility_209270), you can use the chainring* with a Shimano setup, but you might get some chain rub (scroll down to compatibility grades). If you are not running a SRAM Yaw FD, I'd probably just avoid these rings and get normal ones.

- See the "Swapping chainrings" section of the same article on issues with the small ring.